# Kivy, using images instead triangles

Tags: python, kivy

Hello i am making game in Kivy, in Python. I would like to use some pixel image instead boring triangle. Can i do it?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Using the `Image` widget, you could scale, resize and rotate with the help of the [scatter widget](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scatter.html) if needed. Ensure that the image has an alpha channel to not see the background of the triangle image.